# Second lock on same variable in a single expression blocks indefinitely

Tags: rust, deadlock

I have a `Node` containing a `Mutex` on a shared `Protocol` which is in turn used among different threads within a thread pool:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct Node {
    thread_pool: ThreadPool,
    protocol: Arc<Mutex<Protocol>>,
}

pub struct Protocol {}
impl Protocol {
    pub fn is_leader(&self) -> bool {
        // Do stuff...
    }

    pub fn is_co_leader(&self) -> bool {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

When I try to acquire a lock on the `protocol` of the `Node` within the same `if`-statement, the code within that statement is never executed.

```
impl Node {
    pub fn sign(&mut self) {
        let protocol_handler = Arc::clone(&self.protocol);

        self.thread_pool.execute(move || {
            if !protocol_handler.lock().unwrap().is_leader()
                && !protocol_handler.lock().unwrap().is_co_leader()
            {
                // This is never executed
            }

            // And this neither...
        })
    }
}
```

However, if the values of the method invocations are assigned to two variables, everything works as intended:

```
impl Node {
    pub fn sign(&mut self) {
        let protocol_handler = Arc::clone(&self.protocol);

        self.thread_pool.execute(move || {
            let is_leader = protocol_handler.lock().unwrap().is_leader();
            let is_co_leader = protocol_handler.lock().unwrap().is_co_leader();

            if !is_leader && !is_co_leader {
                // Either this will be executed
            }

            // or this ...
        })
    }
}
```

Is there any specific cause for Rust's behaviour to wait indefinitely in the first case?

Comment: For me your two variants don't make a difference. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, where does `ThreadPool` come from? Where is the code that constructs a `Node` and calls it? Why do the functions returning `bool` not return any values? Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: This seems *really* racey. What if another thread mutates `self.protocol` in between `is_leader()` and `is_co_leader()`? I suspect you should only `lock()` once (and probably not release the lock until after the `if` statement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an MCVE for your problem:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let foo = Mutex::new(42i32);

    let f1 = (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_ones();
    println!("f1: {}", f1);
    let f2 = (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_zeros();
    println!("f2: {}", f2);

    let tot = (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_ones() + (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_zeros();
    println!("tot: {}", tot);
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=360524e23e47a345bf92700fcfd0511c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

When running this code it will print `f1` and `f2`, then hang when trying to compute `tot`.

The problem is that `Mutex::lock` returns a `MutexGuard` which releases the lock automatically when it goes out of scope. In the example above, the guards go out of scope at the end of the expressions in which they are used. So when I write:

```
let f1 = (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_ones();
```

I acquire the lock, read the value, and release the lock. Therefore the lock is free when computing `f2`.

However, when I write:

```
let tot = (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_ones() + (*foo.lock().unwrap()).count_zeros();
```

I acquire the lock, read the value, try to acquire the lock again and only release both guards at the end of the line. This causes the code to deadlock when I try to acquire the lock for the second time without having released it first.

Note as commented by trentcl that your two steps example is subject to race conditions if things are changed between the two times the mutex is locked. You should rather use something like this:

```
impl Node {
    pub fn sign(&mut self) {
        let protocol_handler = Arc::clone(&self.protocol);

        self.thread_pool.execute(move || {
            let handler = protocol_handler.lock().unwrap();

            if !handler.is_leader && !handler.is_co_leader {
                // Either this will be executed
            }

            // or this ...
        })
    }
}
```